# How do I compute the gradient vector of pixels in an image?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, gradient

I'm trying to find the curvature of the features in an image and I was advised to calculate the gradient vector of pixels. So if the matrix below are the values from a grayscale image, how would I go about calculating the gradient vector for the pixel with the value '99'?

```
21 20 22 24 18 11 23
21 20 22 24 18 11 23
21 20 22 24 18 11 23
21 20 22 99 18 11 23
21 20 22 24 18 11 23
21 20 22 24 18 11 23
21 20 22 24 18 11 23
```

Apologies for asking such an open ended question, I've never done much maths and am not sure how to start tackling this.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you're using Matlab, you can do:

```
X = your matrix

[gx,gy] = gradient(X); % first order gradient

[gxx,gxy] = gradient(gx); % second order gradient

[gxy,gyy] = gradient(gy); % second order gradient
```

To find the curvature of features I advise you to look into the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Hessian matrix. A hessian matrix is a square matrix of second-order derivatives of a scalar valued function. In this case the scalar field is the intensity, and the second order derivatives are $g_{xx}$, $g_{xy}$, $g_{yy}$.